# Can paperclip be used for non image uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am experimenting with paperclip to work with my rails application, most examples that I found are for image attachments, I have a use case where a user can upload a .json file and I want to attach it to my ActiveRecord model. Can paperclip be used for such a use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Simply going to the GitHub page reveals this.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

"Easy file attachment management for ActiveRecord"

Comment: hi，I want to upload a non-image file(*.ai) with paperclip, but it raise the errors: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity. I just follow the offical readme to config my paperclip. why?